# Variation of MOSFETs with same W/L ratio

Tags: mosfet, simulation, nmos

In MOSFET devices (let's say NMOS for this example), I know that the drain current has a formula:
$$Id=\frac{\mu nC_{ox} }{2}\cdot \frac{W}{L}(V_{GS}-V_{th})^2(1+\lambda V_{DS})$$
For this circuit:
[image]

I got this result:
[image]

As expected, the drain current of M4 (2 M1 Transistors in parallel as shown by the multiplier m=2) is equal to the drain current of M1 multiplied by 2.
As shown in the graph, Id(M4) is equal to 2*Id(M1).

I also know that the drain current of M2 is different to M4 because of the fringe effect.

However, I am not sure on the effect of varying the lengths of this MOSFET (with the same W/L ratio) in the transistor M3.

Answer (score 3):

There are many effects that come into the picture when you change the length of the MOSFETs. The threshold voltage of the MOSFET changes due to roll-off and DIBL (Drain-Induced Barrier Lowering).

\$V_{T}\$ roll-off - Charges in the channel near the source and drain are supported by the gate and also by the depletion region inside the source and drain. Thus charges needed to be supported by the gate are less or \$V_{GS}\$ required to achieve the threshold is less.

DIBL - Drain voltage causes additional barrier lowering at the source end. This reduces the amount of barrier to be lowered by \$V_{GS}\$ to achieve the threshold.

You need to know the physical effects that are modeled by the MOSFET model you used. There are approximate expressions for including threshold voltage roll off and DIBL to the current equation.